# How to restrict reactjs from cacheing API data

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I am new to reactjs. In my project front end is react and backend in slim.There I noticed a issue that whenever I make changes in API then its not reflected on front end until and unless I dont clear my browser cache.Its also happening for production project.

Is I am missing anything here in reactjs? Why it cacheing the API data

Comment: react doesn't handle any caching whatsoever. how are you retrieving the api data?

Comment: In component will mount life-cycle.I have created a service as functional components where it send the data to particular api

Comment: can you add the code for the component? It's too hard to tell what the issue is with the current information. also, `componentWillMount` is going to be removed from react. use `componentDidMount` instead

Comment: ok i will update it

Answer (score 0):

A solution that may work is to comment out registerServiceWorker and import unregister and invoke it.

```
import App from './App';
// import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { unregister } from './registerServiceWorker';
unregister();
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Refer here for other suggestions! (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1910)